# '.each do' is leaving some line like "#<Table:0x224af70>"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying to prepare a json object for my rails app.
Here is my code:

```
#videos_controller

 def show
     @video = Video.find(:all,
                         :conditions => { :published => true, :trash => false },  
                         :order => 'RANDOM()', :limit => 1)


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json {render :partial => "videos/show.json"}
    end
  end


#_show.json
<%= @video.each do |video| %>
{
    "video_link": "<%= video.link %>",
    "video_id": "http://website.com/videos/each/<%=video.id%>"
}
<% end %>
```

but at videos/show.json I'm getting something like that

```
{
  "video_link": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6rmWnwtps6I",
  "video_id": "http://website.com/videos/each/51"
}
#<Video:0x220a060>
```

How to avoid the nasty last line and were does it getting from? I think, becouse of that, it doesn't allow me to work with json object properly. I know, that answer is pretty simple, but just can't get it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take out the equal sign in the line `<%= @video.each do |video| %>` so it's just `<% @video.each do |video| %>`.  The segment you're seeing is the default to_s method which is being returned from the each method.

Comment: I knew, that was something simple! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
<%= @video.each do |video| %>
```

to this:

```
<% @video.each do |video| %>
```

Since you’re outputting text in the body of the loop, you don’t want to output the loop itself (the result of which is the enumerable itself).